Can't select sub categories on filter in the products category page
I work on Prestashop 1.7.8.11 website, and I have an issue when it comes to filter products by categories on a products category page.
Indeed, let's say that I have this category tree :
-> Woman    
   -> Clothes         
      -> Tee-shirt       
      -> Trousers    
   -> Shoes       
      -> Sandals       
      -> Sneakers

Now, if I'm on the Woman category page, I have a filter with checkboxes to target specifics categories.
This filter contains all the sub categories of the Woman category (Clothes, Tee-shirt, Sandals, etc).
I can check the checkbox of the 1st level (Clothes ans Shoes), it work perfectly.
But when it comes to select the 2nd level (Tee-shirt, Trousers, etc), it doesn't work at all. The ajax works properly, but when the request has finished, it returns all the "Woman" products, and the checkbox of the 2nd category level that I want remains unchecked.
I'm wondering if there is anything to configure in the Prestashop settings.
Thank you for your help ! 

Is this a programming-related question?

I don't know if there is anything related to programming. I'm a developer so I can do programming if needed. My request is just that the 2nd category level works the same as the 1st category level

StackOverflow is meant for specific programming-related question, please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]

Okay right, thank you for that
